# Connect to Redshift from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect to my `Redshift` database from my `AWS Lambda` function:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname="my_dbname",
    host="my_url",
    port= 5439,
    user="username",
    password="my_password")

cur = con.cursor()
```

But I can't access my database, my function raises the following error:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "my_url" (54.217.83.88) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

Can i get some help with this please ? (and if possible I'd like to have a very detailed answer, because I'm new to AWS )

PS: I know that I have to configure the VPC, but I don't know what to do exactly

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Your goal is to have the AWS Lambda function communicate with the Amazon Redshift cluster within the same VPC, via private IP address. This keeps the traffic within the VPC.

- The **AWS Lambda** function will need to be configured to connect to a private subnet in the same VPC as the Amazon Redshift cluster.

See: [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)

- Either connect to the **Private IP address** of the cluster or (preferably) follow the directions on [Managing Clusters in an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-clusters-vpc.html) to enable `DNS Hostnames` and `DNS Resolution` on the VPC so that the host name will automatically resolve to the Private IP address.
- The **Security Group** associated with the Amazon Redshift cluster will need to permit inbound traffic on port 5439 from the CIDR range of the the VPC (or as appropriate).

See: [Amazon Redshift Cluster Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-security-groups.html)