# Unable to connect AWS redshift from AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, node-modules

I'm trying to connect to AWS Redshift from my AWS Lambda function:

```
var Redshift = require('node-redshift');
const getLOOKUP_LOV_JSON= async ()=>{
 try{

   
        
    var client = {
        
  host: "redshift-host",
  user: 'admin',
  database: 'dev',
  password: 'password',
  port: "5439"
  
};
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      
      
var redshiftClient = new Redshift(client, {rawConnection: true});
     
      
           console.log("before Connect");
 redshiftClient.connect(function(err){
       console.log("after connect");
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
    else{ 
      
      redshiftClient.query('SELECT * FROM "Persons"', {raw: true}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
          
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
        else{
          console.log(data);
         redshiftClient.close();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

My code execute till before connect method ,I did not get any issue in my logger,it's print "before Connect" only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Redshift from AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654180/connect-to-redshift-from-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Lambda function will need to be configured to connect to a private subnet in the same VPC as the Amazon Redshift cluster.

you would be getting timeout issue. to fix this you need to put your lambda function in VPC
you can do that following the tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Then add inbound rule in security group of Redshift for lambda function security group on port 5439
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-security-groups.html